# Navigation bar based on role in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, uinavigationbar

How to create a navigation bar based on user roles, some user dont have access to some pages

home, users, messages, org

only few have access to org. and there are similar situations in my website. Guide me on this.

Comment: Please explain what type of navigation menu you're using. Is it a custom navigation bar that you created, or part of a component library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="first">
                    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Contributor"))
                    {
                        <span>@Html.ActionLink("Contribute", "Index", "Epub")</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Publication", "Index", "Epub")</span></li>
                            <li><span>@Html.ActionLink("View History", "SubmissionHistory", "Epub")</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                    </li>
```

Just make sure to check for each role type for your users. If they are in that role they will get shown that menu option.

Comment: I could not understand this, can you explain a bit more, is the contributer a role, and which one goes into the navigation bar and where have you specified its URL.

Comment: Well this is MVC3 so the @Html.ActionLink is my link you may need to modify for your specific project.

Comment: Contributor is a role.. you can change this to anything you like.